# $\|\sum_ia_i g(x-i)\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\le (\sup_x \{\sum_k|g(x-k)|\})\|a\|_{L^p(\mathbb{Z})}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $a=\{a_i\}$ be an arbitrary sequence of complex numbers with finitely many non-zero terms. Consider the function $f(x)=\sum_ia_i g(x-i)$, where $g$ is a good function. Prove that for any $p\in (1,\infty), \|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}\le C\|a\|_{L^p(\mathbb{Z})}$, where $C=\sup_x \{\sum_k|g(x-k)|\}$

Comment: Made a stupid wrong comment. Can't see how to delete it, so I'm editing it to this instead... sorry.

Comment: That was quick. Tried to delete my comment a few seconds after writing it. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out myself. First using change of variable to reduce to problem to the following inequality: 
$$
\sum_k(\sum_i|a_{i+k}||g(x-i)|)^p\le C^p\|a\|_{L^p(\mathbb{Z})}^p
$$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.
Then the above inequality can be proven by Minkowski's integral inequality.